# Change all row values in Pandas dataframe in date format "mm/dd/yyyy" to "yyyy-mm-dd"

Tags: python, pandas

Like the title states, I have two csv files I have read into a Pandas dataframe and I want to join the two tables on their "Dates" column values. I'm having an issue converting the special character "/" to "-" and switching the ordering to year-month-day. Any easy quick way that will convert all the row values from the "mm/dd/yyyy" format to the correct "yyyy-mm-dd" format for the join?

Comment: Have you tried using `pd.to_datetime`?

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%m/%d/%y')`

Comment: Thanks, yeah just need to convert both to datetime and the join worked.

Answer (score 1):

When you read your csv adding [`parse_dates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

```
pd.read_csv('q.csv',parse_dates=True)
```

Or

```
pd.read_csv('q.csv',parse_dates=['Dates'])# your date format column here
```